# Build dependencies with new Android 14 build.xml

Tags: android, ant, build

I've migrated to new build.xml using "android update" to my existing project, it builds all fine with SDK 14 for "ant release". All jar dependencies from libs folder are automatically added.
One of the jar (dependency) is inside another subfolder (not libs), how do I include it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it in `libs/`.

Or, possibly, symlink/hardlink to it from `libs/`.

Comment: For some reason, I cannot. What is the alternate?

Comment: @taranfx: If your computer does not allow copying or linking to files, you will be unable to compile the project, regardless of any issues with JARs. The compile process involves creating and copying lots of files -- if your computer cannot do that, there is no point in you continuing doing software development.

Comment: jar.libs.dir= in ant.properties works for external directory. But how do I specify multiple directories? What is the separater in this case?

Comment: @taranfx: Ant supports either `:` or `;`, regardless of OS, for things like the `classpath`. Whether Android's build scripts are using `jar.libs.dir` that way, I cannot say.

Comment: @taranfx: Then I repeat my original solution: move, copy, or link the JAR into `libs/`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ADT's bug. Only the `libs` and `top level allowed`